# How to make the gradient border stay at the screen

Tags: css

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d3ckg18e/)

Html

```
<div class="content">Blabbles</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

html{
    border-image: linear-gradient(rgba(248,80,50,1), rgba(255,153,51,1)) 40% repeat;
    border-width: 10px;
}
```

Attempted to have gradient border stay around the screen but when the content is longer, the content pass through and the border is scrolling up/down.

Tried both: position: fixed and background-attachment: fixed but they doesn't make border to stay on screen no matter whether content is longer or shorter.

Also how to make the content go through behind the border if it is longer?

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan: I think that is probably correct

Comment: No need to do anything special, view my answer, very simple :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Codepen** http://jsfiddle.net/d3ckg18e/5/

---

CSS code (no need to set a `height`/`min-height` to `html` or `body` element

```
body:before {
    box-sizing : border-box;
    position   : fixed;
    z-index    : 1;
    height     : 100vh;
    width      : 100%;
    content    : "";
    border-image : linear-gradient(rgba(248,80,50,1), rgba(255,153,51,1)) 40% repeat;
    border-width : 10px;
    pointer-events: none;
}


.content {
   padding: 15px;
}
```

---

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** Incorrect answer, this is not specifically what the OP has wanted. I will still keep this here in-case this could help someone else.

---

This can be done simply by putting `height: auto` and `min-height: 100%`. I added this to a wrapper so you where not directly styling the `body`. Here is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/d3ckg18e/3/), but also here is the code I used:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#wrapper {
    border-image: webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(248,80,50,1), rgba(255,153,51,1)) 40%     repeat;
    border-image: moz-linear-gradient(rgba(248,80,50,1), rgba(255,153,51,1)) 40%     repeat;
    border-image: o-linear-gradient(rgba(248,80,50,1), rgba(255,153,51,1)) 40%     repeat;
    border-image: ms-linear-gradient(rgba(248,80,50,1), rgba(255,153,51,1)) 40%     repeat;
    border-image: linear-gradient(rgba(248,80,50,1), rgba(255,153,51,1)) 40%     repeat;
    border-width: 10px;
}

.content{
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 10px auto;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

---

**P.S.** I also made it so the gradient will work on all browsers.

Comment: This is simple but I think this is also different from what OP actually wants. This makes the border span the height of the content whereas OP seems to want it to span the content of screen height and stay fixed.

Comment: @Harry, Yes I realized this after I made my post :( Fabrizio has the correct answer.

Comment: I did the same mistake with my original comment to the question too. So could understand :)